# Twitter API Authentication Flow Misunderstanding

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I don't quite understand the api flow for twitter on a per-user basis for API transactions.

Here's my understanding of the user transaction flow:

1./ User signs into our web application.

2./ User authenticates with twitter and then the API sends the user back to a callback destination with a provided oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.

3./ We store the oauth information into a database.

4./ Now we have there access tokens and can send tweets on their behalf without needing them to log into the application again.

HOWEVER, this is not working correctly. When I try to supply the oauth token information, i'm getting invalid or expired token. OK so instead i supply the oauth token provided to me with the user oauth tokens given by the owner of the app and it works.

**I think I'm mishandling the authentication process.**

I'm reading here at the [authentication docs](https://dev.twitter.com/web/sign-in/implementing).

Can anyone help me understand **how i get my app to handle status updates on a per user level**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. However I read for twitter there is no expiration

Answer (score -1):

This is the actual transaction flow your application will take in order to use Twitter:

1. Register your application to Twitter to obtain an OAuth `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`. This is for Twitter to identify the application that your user will **authorize** to access it's account.
2. When the user wishes to Tweet or access their Twitter resources through your app, The OAuth handshake process will redirect to Twitter, with the application's `consumer_key` so that the user will authenticate on Twitter directly. Once user authentication is successful, Twitter will provide your application with an `access_token`.

That's essentially what happens, except that Twitter uses OAuth 1 protocol so the handshake is more lengthier.

Access Tokens do expire for security reasons. It's like when you login to a system, the session is active for a period. When they do expire, you will have to request for an access token again.

I don't know if that explains your question.

Comment: Right. I have the access tokens provided upon authorization.  Its telling me when I use them invalud token

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library to do OAuth authentication?

Comment: Do I need to authorize and get new access tokens every time I want to post?

Comment: In OAuth 2, you can refresh your access token when it expires. Unfortunately,  this is not possible with OAuth 1.

Comment: @jkushner did you find a solution? what did you end up doing?